# The wire is broken into half

Tags: phrase-request

The light can't on.

> The wires are *broken*.
>
> The wires are *broken into half*.

Do they describe well as the image below?

[image]

(If look carefully, it actually are 2 wires that broken. There are a little wires on the top, not broken from the bulb.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one, except the preposition to use in this context is *in*, not *into*:

> The wires are broken **in** half. `(correct)`
>   The wires are broken into half. `(incorrect)`

You could also omit the “in half” part altogether, but, when you say merely the wires are **broken**, that simply means the wires are not functioning properly. So, it could be the wires look fine but they are not conducting properly. Or it could mean the wires have physically broken apart.

However, when you say the wires are **broken in half** (or *broken in two*), that means the wires have a physical break (like you’ve depicted in your image).

One other note: Some might argue that “broken in half” implies the two pieces of wire would both roughly the same length (which is not the case in your diagram). However, I think that’s a largely pedantic distinction, and find that people often say “broken in half” when they mean “broken in two” – even when the two pieces aren’t equal or nearly equal. For example, the caption for this image (found on the web) was “pencil broken in half”, even though the two pieces are clearly not the same length.

[image]

Comment: The pencil pieces are much closer to being equal lengths than the original poster's lead wires are.

Comment: @Jasper - Perhaps so, but I still think my point holds true: we native speakers will often say "broken in half" when we mean "broken in two."

Answer (score 2):

The verbs **break**, **split**, **divide**, **cut**, and so forth can be complemented by a prepositional phrase introduced by   **in** or **into**.

Native speakers *tend* to prefer a singular object for **in** and a plural object for **into**:

> The pie was cut in half.
>
> The pie was cut into halves.
>
> The cars were divided into groups: high performance, family vehicles, and off-road/utility.

This is not an absolute rule but a strong tendency.

With respect to your picture, I would say

> The lead wires have been **severed** (just below the base of the bulb).

That is a passive form; it uses the past participle of the transitive verb **to sever**.